# PDO Parameter binding causes exception

Tags: php, mysql, session, pdo

I'm trying to bind a parameter to so i can query the database based on a `WHERE` clause, which checks the users username, which is stored in a `SESSION`. The username is definitely being stored in the session, since i can see it when i `var_dump($_SESSION)` so i know that's the cause of the issue.

Instead of getting the id returned, i get the exception. When i change `:user` for `'Maverick'` for example (a valid username from the database, obviously), it will return the id. Any ideas?

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

try {
    $result = $db->query("SELECT id FROM user_info WHERE username = :user");
    $result->bindParam(':user', $username);
    $result->execute();
    $user_info = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} 

catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Could not retrieve user's ID";
    exit;
}
```

Not sure how related it is, but when i do in fact replace :user with Maverick and then do `echo $user_info` it doesn't return anything, but when i do `var_dump($user_info);` it shows the following; `array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> string(2) "59" } }`

I guess my question is technically a 2-part question. Help much appreciated.

Comment: In your catch block, put `echo $e->getMessage();` to see what the error is.

Comment: Thanks, that's really useful! I changed the prepare back for the sake of testing out the getMessage and it tells me what the error is as you'd expect. Excellent little bit of kit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to change your query to reflect the pdo bind param structure per doc here
http://www.php.net//manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

try {
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM user_info WHERE username = :user");
    $result->bindParam(':user', $username);
    $result->execute();
    $user_info = $result->execute();
} 

catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Could not retrieve user's ID";
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want [`prepare()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) instead of `query()`:

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM user_info WHERE username = :user");
$result->bindParam(':user', $username);
$result->execute();
```